# which datatype should I use in order to create a column on a oracle database table that supports 10500 characters?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a statement for the creation of an specific table that one of the columns supports 10500 characters.
It should looks like this:

CREATE TABLE Example1(
column_one VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
column_three VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,
column_four VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL,
column_five VARCHAR2(1) NULL,
column_six VARCHAR2(40) NULL,
column_seven VARCHAR2(4000) NULL,
**column_eight VARCHAR2(10500) NULL, <-----------this is the column with the problem**

The problem is that when column_eight its declared, varchar2 doesn't support so many characters, and the log says:

ORA-00910: longitud especificada demasiado larga para este tipo de dato
00910. 00000 -  "specified length too long for its datatype"
*Cause:    for datatypes CHAR and RAW, the length specified was > 2000;
otherwise, the length specified was > 4000.
*Action:   use a shorter length or switch to a datatype permitting a
longer length such as a VARCHAR2, LONG CHAR, or LONG RAW

But it doens't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of varchar(max) in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414817/what-is-the-equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

This parameter was introduced in 12c:

> Oracle uses the MAX_STRING_SIZE parameter for controlling the maximum
> size. If the MAX_STRING_SIZE is STANDARD , then the maximum size for
> VARCHAR2 is 4000 bytes. In case, the MAX_STRING_SIZE is EXTENDED , the
> size limit for VARCHAR2 is 32767.

Please read the Oracle docs to understand the implications of setting this parameter.

Alternatively, the CLOB type is an option for storing large strings.

Hope helpful.